# Top values from a JSON column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following general schema:

```sql
create table stats (
    indicator varchar(128) not null,
    data json not null
)
```

I have a particular row inserted into that table that looks similar to this:

```sql
insert into stats (indicator, data) values ('actions', '{"John":3,"Jack":1,"James":7,"Jess":3,"Mary":6,"Nathan":2}')
```

I need to obtain for this particular row the top three actions count and the associated names (sorted descending by value).

Desired result - note that for this particular value set, the top "three" actions result in four names listed:

```
Name  | Actions
--------------
James | 7
Mary  | 6
Jack  | 3
Jess  | 3
```

I require a MySQL-only solution as actual data may contain hundreds of thousands of values.

Comment: Usually you have some sort of processing behind the raw mySQL query, like PHP, C or whatever.

PHP for example has the ability to decode the JSON string to an object and then you can sort the stuff whatever way your want. I am afraid I know of no way to do this with mysql alone though, seeing how for mySQL your value is just a plain string.

Comment: Alternatively, you need to revise your database scheme, as in: 'stats' does not have all the data in one dataset, but there are multiple datasets, one for each user.

Comment: To add to the above comments, there might be some way of writing a query in MySQL, but your user data should be in a JSON array, not as separate key value pairs for each user.  You need to fix your data model as suggested above.

Comment: Json_table() function could help as it can convert a json structure to a traditional sql table. However, the whole data structure could vey easily be done in traditional relational table and then the query would be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Not like this.

MySQL is great at comparisons and sorting, but only if the data to be sorted by is in its own column.

Seeing how you require a 'mySQL only' solution but did not state that 'the data structure' is apt to change, I suggest splitting the data into multiple tables in an 1:n relationship.

So we have one table, which identifies the stats, which may look like this:

```
create table stats (
    statID int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    indicator varchar(128) not null,
);
```

You would then proceed to create your 'dataset' by specifying `insert into stats VALUES(NULL, 'action')` and take a note of the automatic ID you're getting.

Then we have a second table, which would look something like this:

```
create table actions (
    statID int(11),
    actions int(11),
    name varchar(32)
);
```

You would then proceed to add one dataset per user using the statID you got earlier, as in `insert into actions VALUES (statID, 7, 'Jack');` etc.

After the tables are filled, you can now do a simple `SELECT name, actions FROM actions ORDER BY actions DESC LIMIT 3` to get the top 3 names.

Alternatively, you can skip the whole 'stats' table (and the associated statID) altogether and just work with the 'actions' table.

However all of this relies on the fact, that all 'actions' are actually formatted the same.

Also, please note that I wrote all code from the top of my head and it may not be syntactically correct.